# Javascript problems after upgrading project from .Net 2.0 to .Net 4.5

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I'm upgrading a web application from .Net 2.0 to .Net 4.5 using Change Target Platform on the project in Visual Studio 2015.

Now when running the application the javascript validation seem to be more sensitive than before. Two examples below.

This code that was accepted before gives error: *split is not a function*

```
var sAreaList = oLogic.tocHelpers.fnGetAreaList("SE1");
var saAreas = sAreaList.split('|');
```

Code below that also was accepted before now results in *Cannot read property 'length' of undefined*

```
if (sItemList.length > 0) {.....}
```

Is there a way to make the validation of the Javascript code so that it works as before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an explanation to the problem from a colleague of mine. It seems that from .Net 3.5 Microsoft encapsulates the response within a parent object.

Take a look at this article for more details. http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/

So by changing this line

```
var saAreas = sAreaList.split('|');
```

...to...

```
var saAreas = sAreaList.d.split('|');
```

I got things going again.

Answer (score 0):

Its more likely whatever `fnGetAreaList("SE1")` points to is being rendered differently rather than an issue with the JS.

Try adding this in to make .NET 4 render closer to previous versions:

`<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" />`

Also it may be worthwhile looking at the [breaking changes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes) to see if anything there affected your app.